# HW for Home WiFi Network

Tags: networking, router, wireless, access-point

I have a wired network already and I would like to add a home wifi network. For full coverage I need more than one access point.

I have two requirements for the wifi network:

a) seamless roaming between access points, clients should not hold on to a weak, first seen AP, but roam to another AP instead.

b) for a better performance, each AP should be connected to the wired network directly - I think this is called 'Ethernet Backhaul'

From the tons of available HW I'm not sure which one to choose, so if you have experience with a similar setup, could you please kindly recommend HW or features I should be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Your buzzword to look for is '**mesh**'.
This provides seamless integration, so the devices are unaware they are changing nodes.

I'd at least have a look at the new Linksys Atlas range - the top end is expensive but a new 'plain' V6 package is about to be released which is 1/3 the price of the high-end tri-band 6E.

https://www.linksys.com/us/c/whole-home-mesh-wifi/

Comment: Thank you. I had a look at the Linksys Atlas Max 6E specs and it supports backhaul, but it does not state if it's Ethernet based or wireless. Is there a way how to find out which one is supported?

Comment: Honestly, idk, I guess it's dredge through the info time, or wait until there's a proper downloadable manual available. It was only just announced so data may be scarce as yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also TP-Link MESH routers. [Here](https://www.tp-link.com/mesh-wifi/) you can find a list of devices supported.

Here is the [list of other devices](https://www.tp-link.com/onemesh/product-list/) (Ethernet over power, repeaters/extenders and so on) which support OneMesh.